# Multiselect in the click wihout ctrl no send array to post

Tags: jquery-ui-multiselect

I used this plugin http://nerdstuckathome.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/multi-select-avoiding-ctrl-button/

and this no send this select in to the POST; this element no exisit in array

Answer (score 1):

I am the author.
If you can be more specific describing the problem, I would be happy to help.
A demo would be perfect if you can build one! :)

PS update 10/10: maybe I have got what do you mean: now the select, when on a form, should be correctly submitted. Check out the version 1.3, just pushed!